# Cwd::abs_path broken on msys, cygwin

Tags: perl, cygwin, msys

I'm trying to get the absolute path to a file provided as a Windows path in Cygwin, respectively Msys (Git Bash) perl. I would like solutions that also work when the supplied path is a "native" Cygwin/MSys path.

I tried using Cwd::abs_path, but that seems subtly broken. Here is a test:

```
user@MYPC MINGW64 /f/Temp
$ perl
use Cwd;
print Cwd::abs_path("F:\\") . "\n";
print Cwd::abs_path("F:\\test.txt") . "\n";
print Cwd::abs_path("..\\test.txt") . "\n";
/f
/f/Temp/F:/test.txt
/f/Temp/../test.txt
```

Directories work, relative paths "work" but don't give the result I'd expect (i.e. .. is not eliminated), but when I add a filename to an absolute path the result is wrong. I had hoped that Cwd would do the path translation for me.

I need to later extract parts of the path (using the functions from File::Spec) and also want open the file. To continue working with the extracted part the path should be native to the perl version used. I want to avoid using cygpath, since I'd like the script to also work with ActivePerl, which understands Windows paths only. I could of course add some ifs to only call cygpath for the unix-y perls.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an absolute path. msys and cygwin are unix emulation environments, and in unix, absolute paths start with `/`. `F:\` is a valid relative path and file name in unix.

```
Linux$ touch 'F:\'

Linux$ ls
F:\
```

In cygwin, `/cygdrive/f/` refers to your `F:`. You can use the command-line utility `cygpath` to convert between native and Windows paths.

```
cygwin$ cygpath -w /cygdrive/c/
C:\

cygwin$ cygpath -u 'C:\'
/cygdrive/c/
```

msys should also have a way of accessing the Windows drive through its virtual unix file system.

Comment: MSys does have some provisions making working with Windows paths easier. For example `perl F:\\Temp\\test.pl` works perfectly fine, even though it's a windows path. I was hoping that MSys perl's library would also help a bit. Cwd::abs_path also touches the filesystem so it could figure out that what it returns is not a valid path and produce an error instead of an invalid path, as it normally does with non-existing paths.